# How to render HTML encoded text in SLIM

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

In my rails application I am using slim for template rendering.
Now I have a field which has some HTML tags.

```
@description = "This is first line <br> second line. some <b>more</b> formatting."
```

In view.html.slim

```
p = @description
```

It is generating following output

```
This is first line <br> second line. some <b>more</b> formatting.
```

Where as I want it to be like

> This is first line 
>  second line. some **more** formatting.

*My question is:* How can I render this html encoded text in slim?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
p = @description.html_safe
```